# C#, how to Draw string on Image inside a rectangle and determine font size according to image size?

Tags: c#, image-processing, drawstring, image-resolution

i need a solution to draw string on an image inside of a rectangle and setting the font size according to the image size (resolution)?

[SAMPLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77dfE.jpg)

as you can see i need to put some text (right-to-left text) inside of that blue rectangle with font size that change according to image sizes

Any Help Will Be Appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Adjust the Text Size according to image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950426/).

Comment: @DourHighArch not exactly!

Comment: To make a font with a specific height in pixels: `Font newfont = new Font(font.FontFamily, fontheight, font.Style, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);`